# WARNING:tensorflow with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conda

I am following Tensorflow's tutorial on building a simple neural network, and after importing the necessary libraries (tensorflow, keras, numpy & matplotlib) and datasets (fashion_mnist) I ran this code as per the tutorial:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

after running this code i received this warning message:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   /Applications/anaconda3/envs/tensorfloe/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630:
>   calling BaseResourceVariable.**init** (from
>   tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for
>   updating: If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.

How do i fix this? 
Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is internal TensorFlow message, you can safely ignore it. It will be gone in future versions of TensorFlow, no actions from your side is needed.

Comment: Why is the message here, when we are supposed to ignore it? Do you have any information from tensorflow issues on that topic?

Comment: @gessulat, what Vladimir told is that this warning is due to an internal tensorflow issue, tensorflow is using its own libraries in a deprecated way, at some point in the future when the deprecated function no longer works, they will have this fixed.  The error message Fikile posted has info about what fires it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar warning when I was using tf.compat.v1.get_variable(...) and what I needed to do was to set the use_resource argument to False. Might help someone looking for a similar warning but doesn't look like the case with you though.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a warning that some features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. It is just for your information that what changes could occur.
Although, you can remove these warnings by

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to filter the tensorflow logs, you can disable the logging with the following lines (tensorflow 2.2):

```
import tensorflow as tf   
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
```

Answer (score -3):

if you want to remove it , you can do run twice for the line of code.

Comment: Wouldn't he still get the warning the first time?

Comment: Hey Anas, Welcome to StackOverflow. Either you should explain your answer with properly formated output in ANswer section or if there is only one-liner answer you should add it in a comment. You can check this answering guideline as well https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Anas is talking about jupyter notebook. On running notebook cell first time, if cell gives warning run it again, cell will not show warning message.