# Understanding WARNING: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a [code](https://github.com/NEGU93/cvnn) using Tensorflow low level API. I am getting the Warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/barrachina/anaconda3/envs/tf-2-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
```

[Here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/g/anaconda/c/T_qBRkZkLfw) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130622/warningtensorflow-with-constraint-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future) it says is low level and internal to Keras so I can ignore it but in my case is probably something I am doing wrong (I barely use keras at all). Therefore, I need to UNDERSTAND why this is happening to see if I can find the problem.